# pd.fillna(pd.Series()) can't fill all NaN values

Tags: python, pandas, fillna

I want to fill the `NaN`s in a dataframe with random values:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame(list(zip(['0001', '0001', '0002', '0003', '0004', '0004'],
                            ['a', 'b', 'a', 'b', 'a', 'b'],
                           ['USA', 'USA', 'USA', 'USA', 'USA', 'USA'],
                           [np.nan, np.nan, 'Jan', np.nan, np.nan, 'Jan'],
                           [1,2,3,4,5,6])),
                    columns=['sample ID', 'compound', 'country', 'month', 'value'])
df1
```

Out:

```
    sample ID   compound    country month   value
0   0001          a           USA   NaN      1
1   0001          b           USA   NaN      2
2   0002          a           USA   Jan      3
3   0003          b           USA   NaN      4
4   0004          a           USA   NaN      5 
5   0004          b           USA   Jan      6
```

I slice the database based on the `compound`  column:

```
df2 = df1.loc[df1.compound == 'a']
df2
```

Out:

```
  sample ID  compound   country month   value
0   0001      a           USA   NaN      1
2   0002      a           USA   Jan      3
4   0004      a           USA   NaN      5
```

Then I tried to `fillna` with non-repeated values using `filler`:

```
from numpy.random import default_rng

rng = default_rng()
filler = rng.choice(len(df2.month), size=len(df2.month), replace=False)
filler = pd.Series(-abs(filler))

df2.month.fillna(filler, inplace=True)
df2
```

Out:

```
   sample ID    compound    country month   value
0   0001           a         USA    -1.0    1
2   0002           a         USA    Jan     3
4   0004           a         USA    NaN     5
```

I expected no `NaN` in the out but actually not, Why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Problem is that your `filler` index is different from `df2`, since `df2` is part of `df1` by boolean indexing, you  can do

```py
filler = pd.Series(-abs(filler)).set_axis(df2.index)
df2['month'].fillna(filler, inplace=True)
```

Answer (score 1):

**Example**

```
s1 = pd.Series([1, 2, None])
s2 = pd.Series([3, 4, 5], index=list('abc'))
```

Run below code

```
s1.fillna(s2)
```

output:

```
0    1.0
1    2.0
2    NaN
```

fillna cant fill NaN of different index

This may not necessarily be the reason. if this cant solve problem, don't just post your code and goals, create and provide a minimal example representing your dataset.

https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example